# How to save a listview after populating it

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-activity

Is it possible to save the item from a listview after it gets closed?

I mean if I start an activity,it populates the list,and immedialty after that,it uses finish() to close itself,it is possible to save thelistview as it was immediatly after population?

Cause if I finish the activity,the items disappear.

I can't run the activity properly,I just need it to populate the list and disappear or remain in background.

Comment: Use SQLite to save data.

Comment: how are you loading list view, is user loading it? You can run a loop on the list view items and save it in content provider if you want it again. but exact answer depends on how you are populating list.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and what I usually end up doing is to create an Application class with variables in it then populate your List there and reuse every time you go back to the Activity if you only want the info saved during runtime.  If your list is large or complex data types then this is the better.  So create a class like this:

```
package com;
/**
 * Global class to hold the application states of the List object
 *
 */
public class MyGlobals extends Application {

    private List obj;

    public List getList() {
        return this.obj;
    }

    public void setList(List o) {
        this.obj = o;
    }
}
```

No you can reference this list anywhere in your activities by doing calling

```
((MyGlobals)this.getApplication()).getList();
```

Also you need to modify your Manifest.xml

```
<application android:name="com.MyGlobals" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
 ....
```